# Problems with internet speed on virtual guest on Debian server

Tags: networking, debian

I am running a Debian guest inside a Debian host using KVM/qemu. There are more guests on the system (three in total). I have set up a secondary IP address, so I don't have to worry about port forwarding and such. Unfortunately, this setup seems to have its own problems.

I set up a bridged network, mainly using this guide: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KvmWithBridge. It works in principle, as in the server is reachable and can reach the internet, but using the network is slow. File downloads from the server use only ~150 KB/s instead of the ~10 MB/s the server is capable of (tested with the host and other guests) even if the server is not busy. Uploads seem to be fine and are capped by my home upload speed. And game servers, especially Minecraft, have a lot of lag. I also tested the connection with ping and have ~15-20% packet loss from my home PC to the server and vice versa.

The other guests do not suffer from these problems, so I suspect there must be an error with my setup.

The output of ifconfig shows a lot of collisions:

```
ens3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet <secondaryIP>  netmask 255.255.255.248  broadcast <secondaryBroadcast>
        inet6 <secondaryIP6>  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether <secondaryMAC>  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 96833  bytes 56268227 (53.6 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 558  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 89692  bytes 93703188 (89.3 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 479793
```

This was shortly after a restart, but the ratio of about 1:6 remains even for longer uptimes.

The configuration of the host interfaces (/etc/network/interfaces):

```
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
  address <primaryIP>
  netmask 255.255.255.224
  gateway <primaryGateway>
  bridge_ports enp2s0
  bridge_stp off
  bridge_maxwait 5

iface enp2s0 inet6 static
  address <primaryIP6>
  netmask 64
  gateway fe80::1
```

And the guest interface:

```
auto ens3
iface ens3 inet static
        address <secondaryIP>
        netmask 255.255.255.248
        gateway <secondaryGateway>
```

There are no interface definitions in either interfaces.d folder.

The interface configuration in /etc/libvirt/qemu/guest.xml:

```
<interface type='bridge'>
  <mac address='<secondaryMAC>'/>
  <source bridge='br0'/>
  <model type='rtl8139'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
</interface>
```

And finally an output of ifconfig on the host:

```
br0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet <primaryIP>  netmask 255.255.255.224  broadcast <primaryBroadcast>
    inet6 <primaryIP6>  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether <primaryMAC>  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 1864843254  bytes 213533425526 (198.8 GiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 4441624847  bytes 564472843883 (525.7 GiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether <primaryMAC>  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 2467024205  bytes 288208293294 (268.4 GiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 5414543354  bytes 732866918235 (682.5 GiB)
    TX errors 1  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.100.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.100.255
    ether <anotherMAC_1>  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 4426221535  bytes 499401359892 (465.1 GiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 1847079213  bytes 234714216395 (218.5 GiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vnet0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet6 <anotherIP6_1>  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether <anotherMAC_2>  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 4397127572  bytes 497903595847 (463.7 GiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 1834595176  bytes 223010663369 (207.6 GiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vnet1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet6 <anotherIP6_2>  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether <anotherMAC_3>  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 29093977  bytes 63464879814 (59.1 GiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 41770457  bytes 13226829212 (12.3 GiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vnet2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet6 <notQuiteSecondaryIP6>  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether <notQuiteSecondaryMAC>  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 937466500  bytes 164125096519 (152.8 GiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 583314253  bytes 47334133493 (44.0 GiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Where the primary IP is the IP of the host, and the secondary being the additional IP for my guest only.

The IP6s of the vnet interfaces seems to be based on their MAC address, which - at least for my guest - differs here only in the first group (fe instead of 00).

Are there any problems with this setup? Should I be checking any other configurations for problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched the network adapter of the guest to the 'virtio' driver, a recommendation I saw in several other posts. Changing it via the config file did not work (might be my error), but changing it via virt-manager did the trick.

The download speed is now the 10 MByte/s I would expect and a quick test with Minecraft showed a big improvement as well.